# Use of Primary Windings in a Dual Primary Mains Transformer

Tags: power-supply

I'm building a Cathode Ray Tube-based oscilloscope. The PSU is very simple: 6.3 V AC for the heater (at 0.6A ), -100 V DC for the negative bias (at less than 1 mA), and +500 V DC for the HT (at about 3 mA).

My 100 W toroidal transformer has dual 110 V primaries, dual 175 V secondaries, and dual 6.3V secondaries.

Wiring the 175 V secondaries will provide 350 V AC which when rectified and smoothed will produce 500 V DC.

Simply connecting one of the 6.3 V secondaries to the heater will work.

My problem is the -100 V DC bias.

Here is my question: Can one of the 110 V primaries be used as a 110 V secondary? There will be no connection between the two windings.

Using one of the 110 V primaries as a secondary would provide about 160 V DC that could be smoothed further and dropped to the required 100 V DC. NOTE: the current requirement for the negative bias is very low and consists mainly of a 100 kΩ potentiometer whose wiper goes to the "brightness" electrode on the CRT.

The transformer (from ANTEK) is highpot tested between all the windings and therefore will provide the galvanic isolation required. There is a screen but that is between the primaries and the secondaries.

The outputs from the PSU will be isolated from enclosure of the scope. The main danger in a scope with this configuration of PSU comes from the 500 V DC HT.

Comment: We don't know the power rating of your transformer but I'd de-rate it by 50% if I was only using one of the primaries. Would it still power the project at 50% of rated power? I'd prefer to keep both primaries (which allows you to use it in 230V-land too) and use a charge pump from one of the secondaries for -100V.

Comment: One 175V secondaries may be used for providing the negative voltage. Be aware that the negative voltage must appear before the +500V and disappear after the +500V ... so as not to burn the phosphorus at the same point ...

Comment: The transformer is rated at 100VA so there'll be plenty of current available even from only one of the primary windings.

Comment: The caution about the order in which the supply rails come up is very relevant. I'll add extra switches so that the heater supply turns on with the power on/off switch. The "bias switch" will be turned after the heater has had a chance to get up to temperature (I usually give it about a minute on my tube power amps), and finally, turn on the HT.

Answer (score 1):

The currents required are low, so not difficult to filter and you can use single rectifiers. One winding for -100 and 2 windings for +500 V.[image]

Comment: Just choose the "good" constants time.

Comment: Thanks, that should work. I'll check the ripple on the 500V DC to make sure the tracing is stable.

Answer (score 0):

Many Thanks to Bravale, Antonio51, and User_1818839.
I tested the circuit and it provides +489 volts and -244 volts. The caps are 470uF at 400 volts. For the positive side, I used 2 of these caps in series and each is paralleled with a 100K, 5W resistor for balance and discharge. For the negative supply, I used a single electrolytic (470uF, 400V) paralleled with a 100K, 5W resistor. I used quantity 5 of 20V zeners and a MJE350 power transistor (rated at 300 volts). The zener chain is fed by a 100K, 5W resistor. The negative bias supply (that controls intensity) is a 2W 100K pot directly across the -100V rail. The focus control is also a 100K, 2W pot at the end of a chain of quantity 4 100K, 0.5W resistors. When powered up, the Mullard (Philips) DG 7-31 scope tube produces an adequately bright, focused pot very close to the center of the tube face with -50V for the grid (intensity) and +58V for the focus.
This supply is a lot beefier than it needs to be but it should be very reliable since none of the components is being stressed by power dissipation or voltage.
Next step is the design of the deflection system. The DG 7-31 has a asymmetric x-deflection which makes the design of the time base simpler for inexpensive scopes.